# Script is working but causing undefined variable error

Tags: php

using this sctip to clean my text file:

```
$list = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$res = preg_match_all("/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\:\d+/", $list, $match);

if($res) {
    foreach($match[0] as $value)
    $listValue .= $value."\n";
    file_put_contents('file.txt', trim($listValue));
}
```

It's working but i got this error message in my log:

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: listValue in /home/local/public_html/scripts/extractor.php on line 22
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Idea: find out what the `.=` operator does.

Comment: Learning the operators would be a good start. 'whatever=' means do something the current value and another parameter. In your case there is no current value when you call .=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initializate variable `$listValue` before doing a concatenation operation

Concatenation operation `.=` is equal to `$listValue = $listValue.$anotherValue`, so if you don't initializate it, php obviously gives you undefined variable error;

```
$list = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$res = preg_match_all("/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\:\d+/", $list, $match);

$listValue = "";
if($res) {
    foreach($match[0] as $value){
       $listValue .= $value."\n";
    }
    file_put_contents('file.txt', trim($listValue));

}
```

Comment: however, this code has no sense at all. Foreach doesn't have a `{` so this is just doing `$listValue` part. Then `file_put_contents` might receive a null value of $listValue if foreach is never triggered

Comment: foreach need only to put value inside listValue. if foreach is never trigged, put contents will write an empty string in file and not null

Comment: @ Sergi Castellsagué Millán { } are not a issue here, we can use like this for single line statements

Comment: If foreach doesn't have an opening bracket, it will use the next single line only.

Comment: JackTurky adding $listValue = ""; solved the issue thank you :)

Comment: @JackTurky: Adding the indentation helps. It is now easier for folks to understand the issue. And a sidenote: Always use the curly brackets :P

Comment: @JackTurky I do know, but in YOUR code, its correct, it will be "", and not null. But in the OP code, it WILL be null. That's what I meant.

Comment: @JackTurky OP = Original Poster.

Comment: ok :) but your comment need to be inside the answer's comment list and not here ;)